# Tags component in primevue, allowing options to select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I am using **Chips** component in primevue. It is allowing to add options manually. But is there any way to allow multiple options to select like autocomplete. Like **combobox**, it allows options to select and we can provide values manually also.